# When shoud I use numpy.mean and numpy.average?

Tags: numpy, average, mean

I was studying statistical analysis in pandas and numpy and I came across

numpy.average
and
numpy.mean

I was wondering how numpy.average and numpy.mean are different. Are there any performance related difference? When should I use each?

I thought the two were basically the same, since they both compute the average of the data. Yet some of the arguments seems to be different on the offical documentation, it seems as though numpy.average can be used to get weighted averages while we cannot on numpy.mean.

Comment: According to the docs np.mean returns the arithmetic mean along the specified axis., while np.average returns the weighted average along the specified axis.  If weights are equal, then the two are synonomous

Comment: These have be discussed in other SO.  If the different parameters are not important to you, you can use either.  You can always do your own time testing, but I doubt if you'll see much difference.

Comment: Your answered made everything clear, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

As an addenda to the comments and answers, let's test the speed for a simple case - axis=0 on a 2d array:

```
In [48]: A = np.arange(10000).reshape(100,100)

In [49]: timeit np.average(A, axis=0)
53.5 µs ± 170 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [50]: timeit np.mean(A, axis=0)
52.4 µs ± 179 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [51]: timeit A.mean(axis=0)
48.2 µs ± 79.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

`average` and `mean` time almost the same.  The method version a bit faster.  The difference lies in the complexity of the outer calling structure, not in the actual calculation.

`np.average` is written in Python (follow the `[source]` line in the docs). For the no-weights case, it ends up using `a.mean`, the mean method of the array. `np.mean` also uses the method (though the outer python code layer is a bit more obscure).